# Metallic Text in 3DViewport looks incorrect

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, texture-painting, text-object

I'm new in blender, and I was just trying a simple TUT to make a cinematic text, and my results where so different than the one in TUT ([cinematic movie text](https://youtu.be/jLqD2_cVdQM))

Simply a metallic text should be correctly metallic in the rendered/material preview(or lookdev some call it), mine isn't, it looks so choppy and weird.
Here's how I see it:
[image]

This is how its supposed to be (same shading)...
[image]

So what's wrong? does my Blender version has an issue rendering 3D Object?
it never looks metallic at all...
can someone help me with this?

Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I shared it at the end of post, thanks for reminding, hope you can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Bump Height* input, not the *Normal* input (the Normal input can be used for example to plug a *Normal Map*):

[image]

Comment: That slight thing did a huge difference, for a second I thought I had some issue with my blender, you just saved me from quitting when I barely just started.. thank you so much <3! .